# Creation of a e-commerce platform

Tags: opencart

I am a web developer. I got a project to build a 'build your own site' concept platform. for example [buildabazaar](http://buildabazaar.com) or [bigcommerce](http://bigcommerce.com)

I tried magento, axiscart but it was not user friendly and suitable to customer needs. But OpenCart is one which meets all mu customer's requirement. Its easily modifiable.
As i am building this for multiple customers , can u guide me how to configure OpenCart to handle multiple customers with admin panel with all the admin panel options for individual customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy. OpenCart supports Multi carts - mutli stores on different domains; you can even limit the user to that particular cart - so create users for that cart admin panel only; however it is a bit tricky and can get messy if not done properly. Can you explain exactly what you wish to do and I will produce a step by step.

The other thing; opencart although is blazingly fast. Scaling needs to be considered. We use multi stores on opencart for some of our projects and use Rackspace cloud servers with 4-6 opencart instances per server which is load balanced, CDN for storage of static files and of course dns load balanced. The memory I would recommend for each store is 2gb with a separate database cloud instance 1 master db at 16gb and 4-5 slave load balanced for traffic at 4-8gb

This depends on traffic and how it grows. The current setup we have can handle up to 4000 orders per day easily. We manage an average 3,500 on average so our application setup is always ready for high demand. We could essentially host opencarts for users as you want to do with effecting our network..

1. Create user reg form
2. Create and update nginx/htaccess with subdomain info
3. Create and copy that info to an installer script based on that subdomain
4. Make the opencart install and config based on that subdomain and data
5. Send user an email abuot cname records so they can have store.com rather that substore3434.yourecomservice.com

It would be something like this. Lot of validation. cURL usage and cron jobs. I personally would use CPANEL/WHM Apache server (I know people are going to negative me on this) but using Nginx would be a nightmare as CPANEL automates scripts using fantastico... you can use nginx later if your project is a success..

Comment: Thank you so much.  what exactly i need is:  whenever customer purchase a plan with restricted products, he should get his store with his admin panel where he can manage his store.  In opencart i am managed to to multistore with single admin panel. but that doesnt work for me. Is there any way to do like this or whenever customer buys a plan a fresh opencart should get installed in a seperate subdomain created by him. Please suggest. Am really stuck here

Comment: Its exactly as same as buildabazaar website. When customer buys a plan he should get his own store with admin panel (not manually creation but automatically ). So please help me in this

Comment: updated my answer.. its not the best answer..

Comment: Can you please explain me the each step in details. Please don't mind. But am beginner for all these things. Please help me.

Comment: Do you have Cpanel? Apache? WHM? If you tell me who your host and package you are on I will post a solution.

Comment: hi, i am actually looking for the same solution too. But my post didn't get well responses in stackoverflow. btw, i found someone providing the multiple store and admin plugin in opencart extension (http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=123&t=48155). currently i own a VPS (CPANEL/WHM), and i'm wondering if there are bandwidth and storage limitation for each customers who purchased my plan and is there any automated process to resolve the DNS when customers add in their custom domain? my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065819/multiple-sellers-e-commerce-platform/11065970#11065970